# The All Seeing Eye

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

I would like to introduce myself to the Puzzling world on Stack Exchange (came from Stack Overflow). I've enjoyed several puzzles here and I would like to begin to participate as I believe brain training is important.

So with respect to me being new here I will post a short and sweet puzzle:

> I can move mountains, rivers, and oceans.
>
> I can erase what you create.
>
> I can make you feel good or bad.
>
> I can tell the greatest story ever told.
>
> I am never-ending.
>
> I see everything and have seen everything.
>
> ***What am I?***

***Final Note***: Since I am new to the Puzzles area, please feel free to correct the tags on this post, as well as comment in some good advice for future posts. If there happens to be a tutorial on writing a good post here then please comment it below and I will update my post to follow those guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE.  As with all the Stack Exchange sites, you are encouraged to [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Assuming this is your first puzzle based on reading @DavidStarkey 's comment, great first puzzle! Or if it isn't, still, great puzzle! :D $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Comment: This was indeed my first puzzle here; I quite enjoyed it! I've really been enjoying the community here! Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Would you happen to be

> Time?

I can move mountains, rivers, and oceans.

> Over time, mountains, rivers, and oceans eventually change shape/paths/location.

I can erase what you create.

> Via erosion, after long enough time all is erased.

I can make you feel good or bad.

> You can have good times or bad times.

I can tell the greatest story ever told.

> This could be any story at all, from [The Greatest Story Ever Told](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greatest_Story_Ever_Told) to any part of history so far.

I am never-ending.

> Effectively, I guess this is true.

I see everything and have seen everything.

> Time is omnipresent in the past, present, and future.

Answer (score 6):

The clues all suggest to me an answer of:

> God (specifically the Judeo-Christian God)

I can move mountains, rivers, and oceans.

> God is the creator of all things, and is fully capable of changing that which he has made. Many passages in the Bible credit God with moving mountains, rivers, and oceans. One (rather poetic) passage that mentions all three: "The sea looked and fled, the Jordan [river] turned back; the mountains leaped like rams, the hills like lambs." [Psalm 114:3-4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+114&version=NIV)

I can erase what you create.

> No matter how creative or powerful human beings are, their endeavors cannot stand against God's power.

I can make you feel good or bad.

> "I form the light and create darkness, I bring prosperity and create disaster; I, the Lord, do all these things." [Isaiah 45:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+45:7&version=NIV)

I can tell the greatest story ever told.

> [The Greatest Story Ever Told](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greatest_Story_Ever_Told) is a movie about the life of Jesus Christ, who Christians believe to be God incarnate. Not only can God tell this story, he is the author and main character!

I am never-ending.

> God is immortal and possibly outside of time itself. "But you remain the same, and your years will never end." [Psalm 102:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+102%3A27&version=NIV)

I see everything and have seen everything.

> God is [omniscient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omniscience) and [omnipresent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipresence).

The only thing that makes me think this is not the intended answer:

> The question at the end is "*What* am I," whereas most people would refer to God as "Who."

Comment: This was actually my first thought too, but I adjusted my answer because of your final point! Funny that we're on the same page! :)

Comment: This can also mean the other versions of God. Especially Krishna and Allah. @El-Guest Funny we all are on the same page! :)

Comment: This was also another unique way of thinking on the topic! I liked this one as well!

Answer (score 6):

This has danger of being downvoted.. My first thought was also TIME.. but another way of looking at it is

> painting

I can move mountains, rivers, and oceans.

> A paint brush can move a mountain from one side of the canvas to
>  another

I can erase what you create.

> A paint brush can erase a painting you created earlier

I can make you feel good or bad.

> A painting can make you feel good or bad

I can tell the greatest story ever told.

> Because a picture is worth a thousand words

I am never-ending.

> You can keep adding improvements to a painting. It is never "Complete"

The only one I am not so sure of 
I see everything and have seen everything.

But...

> A painting in a room sees everything and has seen everything

Comment: Well, you get an upvote from me, anyway -- I like this! :)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please don't worry about being downvoted. It hardly ever happens here.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Until we have more people :P

Comment: This was a very unique way to look at the puzzle. I like it!

Answer (score 4):

Although I think El-Guest most likely has the correct answer, I'd like to add an alternate answer:

> The Infinity Gauntlet from the Marvel Universe?

I can move mountains, rivers, and oceans.
I can erase what you create.

> The infinity gauntlet can do these with ease.

I can make you feel good or bad.

> ["I don't feel so good" (spoilers!)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9H4-u5bLC8)

I can tell the greatest story ever told.

> [Avengers: Infinity War](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/)

I am never-ending.

> This is referencing the stones more than the glove itself. The stones are part of the universe, a supernatural force that shapes reality.

I see everything and have seen everything.

> With the infinity gauntlet, you control reality itself. And it has existed since the beginning of the universe. Thus, it has seen everything.

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but your up and down votes are rot13(cresrpgyl onynaprq, nf nyy guvatf fubhyq or).

Comment: @El-Guest rot13("Jura V'z qbar, unys bs uhznavgl jvyy fgvyy rkvfg. Cresrpgyl onynaprq, nf nyy guvatf fubhyq or... V ubcr gurl erzrzore lbh.")

Comment: That was a good answer! It made me laugh, and the details you've included actually taught me a thing or two about the infinity gauntlet.

Answer (score 4):

First thing that came to my mind was

> Dreams

I can move mountains, rivers, and oceans.

> Can't speak about others but I've dreamed of a moving mountain before

I can erase what you create.

> You don't really control your dream so even if you think of something the next moment in your dream it might be gone

I can make you feel good or bad.

> Nice dream or nightmare

I can tell the greatest story ever told.

> You can dream of anything

I am never-ending.

> Not sure about this one but I think that when your dreaming you don't have any feeling for time so it can feel like an eternity or their is always someone dreaming of something

I see everything and have seen everything.

> Since you can dream of anything I guess dreams have seen it all